# API platform validation isn't blocking the custom operation

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have created a custom operation and put a validation on the columns. The validation needs to be required. The validation is working good and showing the errors messages but the operation is continuing execution which is weird.

My code:

```
    <?php
   
    namespace App\Entity;
   /**
     * @ApiResource(
     *     collectionOperations={
     *          "add_voucher"={
     *                 "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_COMMERCIAL')",
     *                 "method"="POST",
     *                 "path"="/vouchers/add-new",
     *                 "controller"=AddVoucherAction::class,
     *                 "security_post_denormalize_message"="Sorry, Only Commercials can Generate Vouchers",
     *                  "denormalization_context"={
     *                      "groups"={"add_new_voucher"}
     *               },
     *                  "validation_groups"={"Default", "add_voucher_validation"}
     *         },
     *          "get"={
     *               "method"="GET",
     *                "normalization_context"={
     *                      "groups"={"vouchers_list"}
     *                   },
     *                },
     *     },
     * )
     * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"code": "start", "client.firstName":"start"})
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\VoucherRepository", repositoryClass=VoucherRepository::class)
     */
    class Voucher
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;
    
        /**
         * @Groups({"add_new_voucher", "vouchers_list"})
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
         */
        private $code;
    
        /**
         * @Groups({"vouchers_list","add_new_voucher"})
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $discount;
    
        /**
         * @Groups({"vouchers_list","add_new_voucher"})
         * @OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Client")
         * @Assert\Valid()
         * @JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $client;
    }
```

The custom action :

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, Voucher $data)
    {
        $requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $request->request->replace(is_array($requestData) ? $requestData : array());
        $email = $request->request->get('email');
        if ($request->request->get('email') === null) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                [
                    "error" => "Empty Email",
                    "message" => "The email is required !"
                ]
                , Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        $firstName = $request->request->get('firstName');
        $lastName = $request->request->get('lastName');
        $phone = $request->request->get('phone');
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);
        if ($user) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                [
                    "error" => "User exist",
                    "message" => "This email is already used !"
                ]
                , Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        // User Creation
        $user = new Client();
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setFirstname($firstName);
        $user->setLastname($lastName);
        $user->setPhone($phone);
        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        // Other code here not important
        return $user;
    }
```

The first time I send a post method I get the validation errors correctly but the second time with the same data I get the message This email is already used!

Comment: I don't get your logic, especially why do you **return  $user** instead of **return $data**.

Comment: I will return the created user in the end, in this action i create a new client with organisation and create a new voucher, but my problem is even with validation errors the function is executed